# What language/script can I use to embed a .M4V file into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, embedded-video, m4v

I'm trying to embed a .M4V video file on a web page and it seems to disagree with all my attempts.  I need it in this format as it is for someone else's ongoing project.

I am trying to use this java library file to initialize/talk with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qtobject.js"></script>
```

Here is my code attempt (not working, but works when the format is .mov and the script is changed accordingly):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myQTObject = new QTObject("video.m4v", "video_1", "640", "480");
myQTObject.write();
</script>
```

Here is another attempt (also not working):

```
<embed href="steve.m4v" type="video/x-m4v" />
```

Any suggestions as to what I should and/or should not be doing?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not forced to use Quicktime, the Flash based [Long Tail Video Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) is free and can do Quicktime encoded MP4 if the client has Flash 10 installed.

Comment: thanks, but have you used it?  got any code examples i could try?

Comment: ive been down this road actually and they also have disclaimers against using the free version for commercial use

Comment: That's true. But because playing Quicktime Video should be a feature of Flash's core, every other Flash based Video player should be able to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not a reliable solution you can use now, but when the browsers grow up, the video element can be used from within javascript. Imagine doing video resizing using just css.

http://daringfireball.net/2009/12/html5_video_unusable#fnr1-2009-12-21